# Tabbing between anchor tags in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, browser

This document does not appear to tab correctly in Firefox 36. Value of a tags should be logged to console. Works in Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            a {
                height: 10px;
                width: 10px;
                margin: 2px;
                padding: 2px;
                background: mediumaquamarine;
                display: block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" class="tab">1</a>
        <a href="#" class="tab">2</a>
        <a href="#" class="tab">3</a>
        <a href="#" class="tab">4</a>
        <a href="#" class="tab">5</a>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        var tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');

        for(var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
            addTabEv(tabs[i]);
        }

        function addTabEv(el) {
            el.addEventListener('focus', logHTML);
        };
        function logHTML(e) {
            console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
        };

        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It works for me when I click on them. I don't have tabbed enabled in FF (default in that browser), so tabbing does nothing. In Chrome it works when I click or tab (focus) on each link.

Comment: The default is for anchors not to be tabable? They also are not tabable with tabindex explicitly stated. This is contrary to the behaviour it exhibits when you use divs instead.

Comment: Of course anchors are “tabable” by default. And I don’t think this is “disabled” in Firefox by default either.

Comment: But this isn't working in a vanilla install